# Implementing 2FA with Twilio: Handling Backup Codes and QR Codes

Tags: twilio, two-factor-authentication, totp

I'm in the process of implementing 2FA with Twilio at my company, and I have a question about handling backup codes for situations where a user loses their phone.

Specifically, when a user enters their backup code, should I generate a new QR code for them and somehow deactivate the previous one? Or should I continue to display the same QR code that was shown during their initial registration?

I'd appreciate any insights or best practices for managing backup codes in this context. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Hey feranando - OWASP groups providing single use recovery codes under ["Resetting MFA"](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Multifactor_Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#resetting-mfa) so I think it's fair to treat this like a 2FA reset and regenerate the seed.

Are you using the TOTP API? If so this would be the `binding.secret` in the response of the [Factor endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/factor?code-sample=code-create-new-totp-factor&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) which is used to construct the QR code you present to the user.

Comment: Hi, Kelley, thanks for the response, actually Im in charge of designing the migration from Twilio Authy to Twilio Verify API, so im wondering if once the user enters their backup code should I update their factor?? so the Twilio API just update the factor (seed) if I call again a Factor.updater() with a already registered entity. Is this the actual protocol when the user rever their account with backup codes?

Comment: I would delete the old Factor and create a new Factor (and make the user re-scan the QR code generated by this)! If you're doing this as a migration from Authy, you need to create a new Factor.